# Why don't university courses report percentiles together with absolute grades?

Tags: united-states, grading

In any course in university, grades will be reported on an absolute scale, such as A+, A, B+, etc. Why don't these courses also report percentiles to indicate how hard the course was? This is very similar to what the GRE does. For example, I could be in the 95th percentile, which means that I did better than 94% of the students in the class. This would also eliminate the need to adjust grades to fit a particular distribution.

Comment: Some universities figured out that there is no need to adjust to a particular distribution, and relative grades are quite meaningless. You might know more than half of your peers, but if you still don't know the stuff, your knowledge isn't going to be very useful.

Comment: "In any course in university, grades will be reported on an absolute scale, such as A+, A, B+, etc." -- this is not true in general. Many courses / programs / universities grade relatively, even if they give letter grades. For example, approximately the top x% of the class would get an A+, and so on.

Comment: My university does this. https://i.imgur.com/EyHtxV6.png. Your question should be, why doesn't *yours*.

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare for the person giving grades -- having to fine-tune the grading to give valid percentages (and getting complaints that someones friend was 89st percentile, but the student asking only 87th, and that is unfair). Dually, one should assume that these percentages came with quite high tolerances. Maybe one should denote ranges: 90-100 by A, 80-89 by B and so on ....

Comment: @BrtH That's a grade distribution. A percentile would say that someone in the highlighted bar did better than 42-86% of their peers.

Comment: Would this be over a single section, or all sections ever taught? If so, would we recompute the chart each year for all students who ever took it?

Comment: In my University, we were graded on a curve and given A,B,... equivalent grades. The non-exactness of the final grade was to account for different random factors that could affect your marks throughout the year (Which TA corrected your work, consistency of grading, bad exam day etc.). This also gave the professors wiggle room to help students that were on the border of failing.

Comment: It shocks me that universities still 1) grade on a curve, 2) don't assign strict percentage marks to every assessment item. 15 years ago in Australia you knew exactly what mark you would get.

Comment: @Teepeemm, huh, you're actually right. They recently switched to a new interface, I hadn't noticed they removed that. I found this old screenshot of what it looked like and what I meant https://i.imgur.com/9yGwua1.png, the last line: *26% of students got the same or a higher result*. (and some pretty dramatic results)

Answer (score 16):

Actually there are many reasons that contribute to this, though as noted it isn't universal.

First, there is no real basis of comparison between courses, even in the same major, since the tests, unlike, say the GRE, aren't standardized, nor do they have enough data points for valid statistical inference. The numbers, if reported, would be essentially meaningless, though people would try to impute meaning to them.

Across disciplines the issue is even more extreme, of course. How "hard" is a Calculus class compared to one in Ethics? They can both be very hard, but it is impossible to compare them since the student activities are very different as is the basic pedagogy.

Second, and to me, vital, is the fact that introducing percentiles is a form of competitive grading that I find offensive. In my view, a student should be graded based only on their own, individual, performance. The typical A, B, ... grading scheme tries to capture this notion, even if imperfectly. If I get a C it should mean that I, individually, have some deficit, independent of what anyone else achieved or didn't. And note that the grading classifications are inherently broad and inexact as are all of the measures we use to determine grades.

One can do poorly on an exam for reasons other than lack of effort and learning. You might just have gotten too little sleep, or there is a family issue that requires your time and attention. Some instructors throw out the "lowest grade" to account for such things. Others have "fuzzy" boundaries between grade levels, giving the students the benefit of the doubt if they just "miss" a cut.

And of course, tradition plays a role. People know how to evaluate the general grades they see on transcripts from long practice. Even introducing A+ grades a few years ago caused disruption in this. Percentile grading has too much chance of being interpreted incorrectly.

Finally, implied by the above, percentile grades don't really measure "how hard" the course is, but something else. Someone has to be in the lowest percentile even if all students excel.

Don't look for completely "objective" ways to measure human performance and expect that it means exactly what the numbers seem to imply. Even [Usain Bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usain_Bolt) was sometimes slower than other runners.

Comment: I feel that a percent*age* and a percent*ile* are different things to report; while this answer always says "percentage", I think it is about percentiles.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, yes, and I intended percentiles throughout. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: I do not see how giving a student benefit of the doubt when they miss a cutoff nearly is different from moving the cutoff...

Comment: @user2316602: When I did this I always moved the cut-off. Amazingly, I almost always managed to keep those who I felt performed at close to the level of the one or two students who motivated me to give them "the benefit of the doubt" (not in person, but when looking at all their various grades in the course), while having a reasonably large gap before the next grade not making the cutoff. But not always. In a handful of cases over a 20+ year period, I had to include a few students who I thought should be given the lower grade, yet their %'s were above someone I felt otherwise. **(continued)**

Comment: Since I was fully explicit in telling students how to calculate their overall course % (various weightings of quiz and test scores, various quiz and test drop possibilities, homework grades, extra credit for especially difficult take-home problems, etc.), the students were able to calculate their exact course %. Because I have no way of knowing who shares with who their grades, I never allowed, for example, a cutoff for C−/D+ to allow someone below this cutoff getting a C− and someone above this getting a D+. Of course, cutoffs were not worse than 90−100 A's, 80-89 B's, etc. (in the syllabus).

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is:  Why don't we rank students?

Elite universities only accept the top few percent of eligible students.  If elite universities ranked their worst students, those students would choose to enroll at a lower ranked university where they could get a better rank.  Soon, elite universities would have fewer students.  Elite universities don't want that, so they do not rank anyone.  Certain elite business schools take this further and keep all student grades secret.

Other universities copy the elite universities.

There are also no particular benefits to a ranking system.

If your question is: Why shouldn't we rank students?

Ranking encourages competition over cooperation, which reduces student learning.

Comment: I don't think that this answer is true. Elite universities *do* compare their students with each other, and their grades are not comparable with those at lower tier universities. Employers know this, which is why no sane student would trade in a decent grade from Cambridge for a good grade from a lower tier university.

Comment: @AlexB. You are not contradicting my answer.

Comment: "rank" and "compare" are not the same.

Comment: I guess I am explicitly contradicting the statement that weaker students that can get into a top university would prefer worse universities if they knew that they will be lower in the ranking at a top university than at a lower tier one; and I am implicitly contradicting the claim that top universities do not rank students. I think it is pretty clear that awarding grades on a linearly ordered scale constitutes a ranking. The OP was asking why the precise mapping between grades and percentiles is not made public, but I am saying that in an imprecise sense employers know that grades reflect ...

Comment: ... internal rankings to a greater extent than an absolute international notion of "A minusness" or what have you.

Comment: @AlexB. "awarding grades on a linearly ordered scale constitutes a ranking"  Since in most cases elite universities only use the top few categories on the scale, that is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Some universities indeed do provide rankings in one or another manner (I know that for instance [WU Vienna](https://www.wu.ac.at/en/) provides statistical information how you are doing grade-wise in comparison to other students in your year and overall).

The main reason why many (most?) universities don't is because program managers and education managers tend to think of grades not directly as a device to assess how "good" students are, but as an indicator of how well a student achieved the defined learning objectives of the course (if you barely know the minimum after the course, you get whatever the lowest passing grade is, if you achieve all or almost all of the optional learning objectives as well you get the equivalent of an A+). How well a student achieves the learning outcomes is fundamentally independent of how any other student did - it's possible that nobody excelled in a course, and it's possible that everybody learned all there was to learn. In both of these case, the fix wouldn't be to re-scale the grades, but to adjust the learning objectives of the course.

This has the added benefit that grades are more predictable for students, and there isn't inherent competition among students (especially if your university heavily builds on peer instruction, you really don't want any students to withhold knowledge from each other).